# When do solution to differential equations belonging to the same parametric family intersect?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, gradient-flows

#### General Problem

I am interested in studying whether solutions to the Fokker-Planck equation:

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}\label{fp}
\frac{\partial p(x, t)}{\partial t} = \textrm{div}(-p(x, t)\nabla\log q(x)) + \frac{1}{2}\Delta p, \quad p(x, 0) = p_0
\end{equation}

(where $p_0$ and $q$ are probability densities), can intersect at some time $t^\star$, when varying the choice of $q$. More formally, I want to know if there exists a triplet $(q_1, q_2, t^\star)$ such that $p_1(x, t^\star) = p_2(x, t^\star)$, for all $x$, and where $p_1$ (resp. $p_2$) is the solution of \eqref{fp} with $q=q_1$ (resp. $q=q_2$), and $t^\star>0$.

I welcome any pointer to works/fields studying the intersection points of solutions of differential equations (a) belonging to some parametric family and (b) with the same initial conditions.

#### Simpler Setting

Looking first at simpler ordinary differential equations (ODEs), note that the following ODE:
$$\tag{2}\label{ode1}
\frac{\textrm{d}x}{\textrm{d}t} + ax = 0, \quad x(0) = 0, \, a \neq 0
$$
is such that no triplet $(a_1, a_2, t^\star)$ (with $a_1, a_2 \ne 0$, and $t^\star > 0$) verifies $x_1(t^\star)=x_2(t^\star)$, where $x_1$ (resp. $x_2$) is the solution to \eqref{ode1} with $a=a_1$ (resp. $a=a_2$).

On the other hand, for the ODE:

$$\tag{3}\label{ode2}
\frac{\textrm{d}^2x}{\textrm{d}t^2} + k^2x = 0, \quad x(0) = 0, \, \frac{\textrm{d}x}{\textrm{d}t}\bigg \rvert_{t=0} = 1, \, k \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}
$$
the triplet $(1, 2, 2\pi)$ verifies $x_1(2\pi) = x_2(2\pi)$, where $x_1$ (resp. $x_2$) is the solution to \eqref{ode2} with $k=1$ (resp. $k=2$).

As this simpler setting is related to my original problem, I would also welcome pointers to any work in this latter simpler setting.

PS: I added the tag Gradient Flows since solutions to \eqref{fp} are also solutions to the Gradient Flow of $KL(\cdot||q)$ with initial condition $p_0$.

Answer (score 1):

(Partial answer, too long for a comment)

Note that your Fokker-Planck equation can be implicitly integrated with respect to time, i.e.
$$
p(x,t) = p_0 + \int_0^t\left(\frac{1}{2}\Delta p(x,\tau)-\mathrm{div}(p(x,\tau)\nabla\log q(x))\right)\mathrm{d}\tau,
$$
hence for two solutions $p_1,p_2$ :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
   0 &=& p_1(x,t^*)-p_2(x,t^*) \\
     &=& \displaystyle
     \int_0^{t^*}\left(\frac{1}{2}\Delta(p_1(x,\tau)-p_2(x,\tau))-\mathrm{div}\left(p_1(x,\tau)\nabla\log q_1(x)-p_2(x,\tau)\nabla\log q_2(x)\right)\right)\mathrm{d}\tau
\end{array}
$$
which translates locally as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\nabla(p_1-p_2) - p_1\nabla\log q_1-p_2\nabla\log q_2 = A,
$$
where $A(x)$ is an incompressible vector field (i.e. $\mathrm{div}A=0$), since $\Delta = \mathrm{div}\,\mathrm{grad}$. It gives you a condition/criterion to check whether the two solutions can coincide or not; I have a feeling that this condition shouldn't be hard to satisfy because of the "gauge freedom" due to $A$.

Final note : if you relax your problem by admitting different initial/boundary conditions, then it becomes a lot more easier for the solutions to intersect; however, that is perhaps a too trivial result for what you need.